# How to install gcc-3.4 on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu

I need gcc-3.4 to compile some softwares on my Ubuntu 11.10 (32-bit). So I downloaded:

```
cpp-3.4_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_i386.deb
gcc-3.4-base_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_i386.deb
gcc-3.4_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_i386.deb
```

and installed them using `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`. Then I tried to compile a "Hello World" program using `gcc-3.4 hello.c`, but it told me:

```
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:388,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from test.c:1:
/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:7:27: gnu/stubs-32.h: No such file or directory
```

I've did the same thing on Ubuntu 10.10 and I successed. So what should I do on Ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment, this probably requires some self-compilation of the following source package: http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/hardy/gcc-3.4, which is a hassle. Another option is trying to get the package from the source, http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-3.4/ (ftp://ftp.nluug.nl/mirror/languages/gcc/releases/gcc-3.4.6/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install the development package `libc6-dev`.

It contains the `stubs-32.h` file as shown in the [file list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/i386/libc6-dev/filelist).

Use `-I dir` to add the directory to the include search path, where headers are looked for...

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but I've installed it and it was not helpful.

Comment: When I look at the contents of the package it should work. Exactly the same error? (http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/i386/libc6-dev/filelist)

Comment: yes, exactly and i have the file `/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs-32.h` in my computer. but gcc-3.4 still cannot find it. can i ask gcc-3.4 search the path `/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/` for *.h files.

Comment: `-I dir` Add the directory dir to the list of directories to be searched for header files.